# ActionResult to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

I know there are a lot of questions similar, but I didn't get the answer I wanted in any of them.
I want to convert, as it is, an ActionResult to String, by doing something like that:

```
public ActionResult ProductDetail(int id)
{
    // ... lots of operations that include usage of ViewBag and a Model ...
    return View(product);
}
```

To show the product page to the client, but also I want to be able to send it by JSON, like:

```
public JsonResult ProductDetailJSON(int id)
{
    // ... lots of operations that include usage of ViewBag and a Model ...
    return Json(new {
            html = this.ProductDetail(id).ToString(),
            name = ""
            // ... more properties
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So I will **invoke** the Controller Action and get its response (a `ActionResult`, that is actually a `ViewResult`) and turn it into a `String`, but having it created using all the business code of the controller method (including, specially, `ViewBag` usage).

**EDIT Clarification about why I want to to do it that way**

I need to be able to present the product in the browser, so I create my Controller Action called `ProductDetail`, and works perfectly fine.

After that comes the need to have an API that gives, for a given product a JSON object with some meta-data (like sold units, name, etc.) and the View. One option was to send a link to the view and that's all... but the view MUST be inlined as a client requirement.

To avoid code repetition and to keep it clean, I'd like to invoke the method `ProductDetail`, and capture the HTML Raw response to put it inside the JSON response as an `String`.

I've seen others rendering the View with methods like this one:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

But that way **does not execute the controller logic**.

Comment: why you want like that? can you explain why it is needed, it in unclear

Comment: added a clarification, hope it helps

Comment: As I understand you want to get sometimes a common html page, and sometimes a json object, that will contain also the html code as one of its properties?

Comment: Absolutely @ViktorArsanov

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://approache.com/blog/render-any-aspnet-mvc-actionresult-to/) is a working solution.

Create new classes:

```
public class ResponseCapture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpResponseBase response;
    private readonly TextWriter originalWriter;
    private StringWriter localWriter;
    public ResponseCapture(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        this.response = response;
        originalWriter = response.Output;
        localWriter = new StringWriter();
        response.Output = localWriter;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        localWriter.Flush();
        return localWriter.ToString();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (localWriter != null)
        {
            localWriter.Dispose();
            localWriter = null;
            response.Output = originalWriter;
        }
    }
}

public static class ActionResultExtensions
{
    public static string Capture(this ActionResult result, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        using (var it = new ResponseCapture(controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response))
        {
            result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            return it.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

in your json method do this:

```
public JsonResult ProductDetailJSON(int id)
{
    // ... lots of operations that include usage of ViewBag and a Model ...
    return Json(new {
            // ControllerContext - modify it so it accepts Id
            html = View("ProductDetail").Capture(ControllerContext),
            name = ""
            // ... more properties
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: The origin [link](http://approache.com/blog/render-any-aspnet-mvc-actionresult-to/) has changed to [this link](http://blog.approache.com/2010/11/render-any-aspnet-mvc-actionresult-to.html).

Comment: I read this but get stuck on getting the ControllerContext. For debug purposes I would like to convert an ActionResult to the HTML that is displayed.